# Different Modules while export APK

Tags: android, android-studio, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I had 2 eclipse project that one for tablet and the other one is for phone. These projects are importing same another project which is called API.

My goal is migrating to Android Studio.

I created a Phone Project and compiled successfully by using phone (execute) and api (library) module.

API is shared module and both platform using same classes from it.

- An alternative can be creating a tablet module to phone project and configure it using gradle to export proper APK. Am i able to do this? If so, how?

or

- Making tablet and phone project compile this API module from remote like another libraries. I am using Gitlab, so how can i make it mavenized and reference from gitlab and force it to use lastest commit always?

Thanks for your helps..

Wish me luck :)

Comment: use api as a library. Configure an app with 2 flavors (tablet and phone)

Comment: how do i configure it? Doesnt it merge manifest? So would i have 2 launcher?

Comment: You can use the main for the common classes

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you should probably start by making your two versions two flavors of the same application. That way they can share any common resources such as fragments and images, but still have their own versions if necessary. More info on that is available in the [Android Gradle user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

In you project you could either have your shared library as a library project that will be compiled with the rest of the application, which means that the source would live in the same place as the tablet and phone versions.

It could look something like this:

```
| app
| - src
| -- tablet flavor
| -- phone flavor
| libs
| - shared library project
```

If you're new to Gradle, I definitely recommend reading through the documentation because there's a lot of nifty things you can do.

You could also have it as a remote dependency. I've seen several projects lately use [Jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/) with repositories on GitHub as the source. It looks like you will have to use GitHub's Releases feature, but that's easily done.